# Issue on TableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Here i'm developing a expanded `TableViewCell` ,while TableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method i am using to cell expand, here i used two TableView Cell's
[image]

but i need to the button action SecondCell will be expanded.Can you please help how can i implement here is the below code,

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        // disable touch on expanded cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"ExpandedCellIdentifier"]) {
        return;
    }

        // deselect row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             animated:NO];

        // get the actual index path
    indexPath = [self actualIndexPathForTappedIndexPath:indexPath];

        // save the expanded cell to delete it later
    NSIndexPath *theExpandedIndexPath = self.expandedIndexPath;

        // same row tapped twice - get rid of the expanded cell
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandingIndexPath]) {
        self.expandingIndexPath = nil;
        self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    }
        // add the expanded cell
    else {
        self.expandingIndexPath = indexPath;
        self.expandedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row] + 1
                                                    inSection:[indexPath section]];
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (theExpandedIndexPath) {
        [_theTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[theExpandedIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
        [_theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.expandedIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];

        // scroll to the expanded cell
    [self.theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

but i want implement while button taps secondCell will be Expanding.

```
- (IBAction)expand:(id)sender {

}
```

Can you please help me ,Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution which you can achieve the logic easily by creating a separate .xib file by disabling size classes. Use a boolean variable to check whether it is selected. If so, then reload the specific cell and use a delegate method heightforrow and determine that boolean variable here. It is simple... Hope you understood. If not, please do let me know. I'll share my code which I worked out.

Edited the post and below is my code :-

```
    @implementation ViewController
    BOOL sel=NO;
    NSMutableArray *a,*b;
    NSIndexPath *path;
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        a=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Mango",@"Orange",@"Pineapple",@"Cricket",@"Bike",@"Music", nil];
        b=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:a copyItems:YES];
            [self.tview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"cell1" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return a.count;
    }


    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        return 1;
    }


    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        if([[a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Selected"]){
            sel=NO;
        [a replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[b objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else{
        [a replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Selected"];
            sel=YES;
        }

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }

    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        if([[a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Selected"]){
        return 100;
    }
        return 60;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        cell1 *cell = (cell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        // If there is no cell to reuse, create a new one
        /*  if(cell == nil)
         {
         cell = [[listcustomcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         }*/
        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[cell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        NSLog(@"%f",[self tableView:self.tview heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
        cell.btn.frame=CGRectMake(cell.btn.frame.origin.x, [self tableView:self.tview heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]*0.3, cell.btn.frame.size.width*1.3, cell.btn.frame.size.height);
        UIButton *b=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn.frame];

        [cell.btn removeFromSuperview];
        [b setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:b];
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return cell;
    }

    - (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender
    {
        CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tview];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tview indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
        if (indexPath != nil)
        {
//Just make sure that you've selected no selection option for the tableview.
            [self tableView:self.tview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"You've selected a row %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
        }
    }
    @end
```

Create a separate .xib and place the button there. For resizing the button's frame, You need to remove it and add again while refreshing. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Pradheep,thank you can you please share your code it would be helpful

Comment: Thank you @pradheep,i solved this way but i need only while button taps cell will be expand ,not didselectrow

Answer (score 0):

I go through you code , and i think you need only to get the cell. see the below code for getting it.

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now do the same steps what you did in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand/collapse your tableView cell then, 
I have made a demo that gives you the exact behaviour as you want. here is the link: https://github.com/rushisangani/TableViewCellExpand

Please set constraint of your **expand/collapse** views as described in demo.

Its based on the **Content Hugging and Content Compression Resistance Priority**.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (IBAction)expand:(id)sender {
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.theTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPathInner = [self.theTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
  // disable touch on expanded cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathInner];
    if ([[cell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"ExpandedCellIdentifier"]) {
        return;
    }

        // deselect row
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             animated:NO];

        // get the actual index path
    indexPath = [self actualIndexPathForTappedIndexPath:indexPath];

        // save the expanded cell to delete it later
    NSIndexPath *theExpandedIndexPath = self.expandedIndexPath;

        // same row tapped twice - get rid of the expanded cell
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.expandingIndexPath]) {
        self.expandingIndexPath = nil;
        self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    }
        // add the expanded cell
    else {
        self.expandingIndexPath = indexPath;
        self.expandedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[indexPath row] + 1
                                                    inSection:[indexPath section]];
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (theExpandedIndexPath) {
        [_theTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[theExpandedIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    if (self.expandedIndexPath) {
        [_theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.expandedIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];

        // scroll to the expanded cell
    [self.theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                     animated:YES];

}
```